# Eclipse won't load: failed to find a main class

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to download Eclipse onto my flash drive so that it can support itself if I try to use Eclipse on a computer that does not have a JDK/JRE installed and/or I do not have the permissions to install one.

I am able to download it onto the flash drive and run it fine, but the problem arises when I try to make it self-sufficient by downloading a JDK for Eclipse to use on the drive. I have tried many different solutions (yes, I am aware of the abundance of "why is eclipse telling me it cant find main class" questions), but none of them apply to me. I followed [this tutorial](http://cis.csuohio.edu/~sschung/ESC120/Running-Java-Eclipse-From-USB-Flash-Drive.pdf) in my endeavors, but when I run the batch file it comes up with the standard `Failed to find a Main Class in "F:\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.200.v20180922-1751.jar`.

I know the `\\` looks a bit out of place, but I know that's not the problem since I've tried editing the eclipse.ini file to fix the path but it gives the same error (just with `F:\eclipse\plugins\org.[...].jar` instead)

I'd really appreciate any help anyone could give. Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Eclipse? Which version of Java?

Comment: Eclipse 2018-12 and JDK 6u45 Windows 64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse has required Java 8 or newer since the Neon release, in 2016. Update your version of Java.

Comment: _sigh_. Yeah, that'll do it. I don't know why I downloaded an older version- probably referred to an older download page by a link. Thanks.